# Bracket notation on Ruby numbers

Tags: ruby, numbers, square-bracket

I found that when using bracket notation on the number `100` in Ruby, I get this:

```
irb(main):001:0> 100[0]
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> 100[1]
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> 100[2]
=> 1
```

So I assumed it was getting the digits, indexed like this:

```
NUMBER: 1|0|0
        -----
INDEX:  2|1|0
```

I tried this on the number `789` with unexpected results.

```
irb(main):004:0> 789[0]
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> 789[1]
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> 789[2]
=> 1
```

I would expect it to return `9`, then `8`, then `7` if it was getting the digits. From this result, that is clearly not happening, so what exactly does using bracket notation on a number do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the binary bits that you're pulling off. Another way to see this is using `to_s` with an argument indicating the desired base.

```
>> 789.to_s(2)
=> "1100010101"
```

String indexing is from left-to-right, so you can't compare `[]` on the string, but note how (from right-to-left) the digits are 1, 0, 1.

Here's the docs if you're interested: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: Wow, I really would *never* have even considered this! Good to know, thanks! (can accept in 10 mins)

Comment: I didn't know this, either. Cool!